# solve() function freezes CLI in GNU R 3.6.3

Tags: r, ubuntu

(Crossposted from AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230138/cannot-use-the-solve-function-in-gnu-r-with-ubuntu-20-04 )

**I cannot use the solve( ) function in GNU R.** Specifically, whenever I try to invert a matrix using the said function, the console hangs. Below I explain more about this situation.

Consider the code

```
D = matrix(
data = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
nrow = 2,
ncol = 2,
byrow = TRUE
)
solve(D)
```

1. If I launch the code in R called from a terminal, say, Konsole, the session will freeze.

   - I know that the exact timing of the system freeze is when I execute the solve( ) function.
   - According to htop, one of my CPU core is used by 100% when this happens.
2. If I launch the same code within RStudio, the code works as expected. However, if I call it using the terminal inside RStudio, the session hangs.

   - If the solve() function is used within RMarkdown document, the session will freeze and the document will not be generated.
3. Launching R with --vanilla does not resolve the issue.
4. Rebooting the PC, using my external graphic card, reinstalling the r-base-core package in apt, and trying with different terminal emulators do not help.
5. From the documentation of the solve( ) function in R, it can be seen that solve(A, B) actually takes two arguments: A is a matrix, and B a vector or a matrix. If B is a vector, it solves the linear system Ax = B. If B is a matrix, it solves AX = B and returns X. If nothing is given in the second argument, it automatically assumes identity matrix of appropriate size as B. **The first function of solving linear system works.** If I specify matrices as the second argument, however, the same problem happens.
6. Using QR decomposition with qr.solve(A) still works well.

Here are my questions:

1. Has anyone had the same problem as me?
2. I also seek recommendations on how to fix this issue.

For your information, I am using R version 3.6.3 installed from the default apt repository.

Thank you for reading, and stay safe!

---

N0rbert from AskUbuntu gave me a following reply:

> I can't reproduce on clean 20.04 LTS VM. See my steps to reproduce -
>   pastebin.com/R7JhkYJT . Execute it on your machine and share the output. 
>   Also add output of which R and R --version to the question body.

Executing N0rbert's code from an executable bash script file, the session hangs at solve(D).

```
kobyeongmin@odie:~/Temp$ ./r-test.sh 

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> D = matrix(
+ data = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
+ nrow = 2,
+ ncol = 2,
+ byrow = TRUE
+ )
> solve(D)
```

Also, here is the output of which R and R -- version:

```
kobyeongmin@odie:~$ which R
/usr/bin/R
kobyeongmin@odie:~$ R --version
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

Comment: I tried it under R 3.6.3 Windows console, R 3.6.3 Windows gui and WSL/Ubuntu R 3.4.0 console and they all gave an answer for me.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I guess the issue is specific to my machine. I wish I knew how to reproduce the problem for general occassions.

Comment: Did you replace your BLAS lib? It would be in /usr/lib on Linux and on Windows in C:\Program Files\R\R-*\bin\x64\Rblas.dll

Comment: BLAS turned out to be a problem! Thank you for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

I received an invaluable help from the R-help mailing list.
This is due to a bug in the libopenblas0-pthread package, which can be solved by removing **libopenblas-pthread-dev** and **libopenblas0-pthread**, and installing **libopenblas-openmp-dev**.

For more information, refer to the R-help mailing list around early May and also debian-science list: https://lists.debian.org/debian-science/2020/04/msg00081.html